# Is there a deadline to respond to an IRS request for additional documentation?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, section-1256

When I sent in my 2014 tax return late last year, I also sent in an amendment to my 2013 tax return due to a Section 1256 contract loss carryback (I had Section 1256 gains in 2013 and losses in 2014).  I was due to receive a large refund.

I just received a letter from the IRS saying that they cannot approve the refund because they want several pieces of additional documentation.  The letter has no mention of any deadline.

I sent the letter to my CPA, who prepared my 2014 return and the amendment to my 2013 return.  But I have no idea when my CPA will be able to gather up all the documentation and send it to me (he has been very slow in the past).

Is there a deadline for when I need to send the documentation to the IRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the notice. It should usually be explicitly mentioned on the notice.

Since in your case they're rejecting the amended return, you are not limited by the usual 30/60/90 days, but by the dead-line to amend the return. Worst case you can just resubmit the amended return and attach the missing documentation to the submission.

But better to respond to the letter and resolve the issue now than to restart the whole process later. The CPA should already have all the documentation from preparing the return.

Comment: You say they are rejecting the amended return.  Does that mean when I send in the documentation, I need to include the 1040X and all the other forms I included with the amended return?  Or do they still have those on file?

Comment: @void If you send it in response to the letter, based on the instructions they gave you, then they should have everything on file. If you're resubmitting the amended return - just attach all the stuff they asked for to the 1040X in statements.